# how to create an #section link equivalent in Apex 5.1.3?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Is there a way to create a link into the navbar similar to an:

```
<a href="page.html#section1">link</a>
```

I can't find any place in the UI to set the link to a subsection.

Basically I have a page with regions, and I need that my link in the navbar to send to a specific region.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I never did what you're asking, but - when you choose a region, in its properties, under the "Advanced" section, you'll see the **Static ID**. Would it help if you put "section1" in there?